# Optimizing image processing in C#

Tags: c#, image, performance

I am trying to iterate through every pixel of an image in C# and do some minor processing on each. The image is represented in a Bitmap, with processing done with byte pointers. Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ImageProcessingExmp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Tick += ChangeColor;
            timer.Interval = 1;
            timer.Start();
            pictureBox1.Width = this.Width;
            pictureBox1.Height = this.Height;
            pictureBox1.Left = 0;
            pictureBox1.Top = 0;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            bmp=(Bitmap)new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        }
        int timerinc = 0;
        int stride;
        Bitmap bmp;
        BitmapData data;
        public void ChangeColor(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            timerinc+=10;
            Benchmark.Start();
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            
            
           data=   bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
             stride = data.Stride;
            unsafe
            {
                byte* ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;
                // Check this is not a null area

                // Go through the draw area and set the pixels as they should be
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    int yTimeStride = y * stride;
                    byte y2 = (byte)(y > 255 ? 0 : y);

                    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                    {
                        int addressToAssign = (x * 3) + yTimeStride;
                        byte x2 = (byte)(x > 255 ? 0 : x);
                        ptr[addressToAssign] = x2;
                        ptr[addressToAssign + 1] = y2;
                        ptr[addressToAssign + 2] = x2;
                    }
                }

            }
            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Benchmark.End();
            double seconds = Benchmark.GetSeconds();
            //MessageBox.Show(seconds.ToString());
            richTextBox1.Text += seconds.ToString()+'\n' ;
            richTextBox2.Text += DateTime.Now.Second.ToString()+'\n';
            pictureBox1.Image=  bmp;
            String[] lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
            double avg = 0;
            double sum = 0;
            double num = 0;
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show(line);
                double tet = 0;
                Double.TryParse(line, out tet);
                sum += tet;
                num++;
            }
            avg = sum / num;
            label1.Text = "fps = " + (1/avg).ToString();
            tst1.Add(1/avg*20);
            if (timerinc >= 500)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width,pictureBox2.Height);


                data = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                stride = data.Stride;
                unsafe
                {
                    byte* ptr = (byte*)data.Scan0;
                    // Check this is not a null area

                    // Go through the draw area and set the pixels as they should be
                    for (int x = 0; x < tst1.Count; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < (int)tst1[x]; y++)
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                            if (y<bmp2.Height)
                            {
                                ptr[(x * 3) + (int)y * stride] = 255;//b
                                ptr[(x * 3) + (int)y * stride + 1] =0;//g
                                ptr[(x * 3) + (int)y * stride + 2] = 255;//r
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                bmp2.UnlockBits(data);
                pictureBox2.Image = bmp2;
            }
        }
        public List<double> tst1 = new List<double>();
        public class Benchmark
        {
            private static DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            private static DateTime endDate = DateTime.MinValue;

            public static TimeSpan Span { get { return endDate.Subtract(startDate); } }

            public static void Start() { startDate = DateTime.Now; }

            public static void End() { endDate = DateTime.Now; }

            public static double GetSeconds()
            {
                if (endDate == DateTime.MinValue) return 0.0;
                else return Span.TotalSeconds;
            }
        }
       
        
    }
}
```

The FPS is currently around 7. How can I significantly increase it?

[image]

(edit)
Tried changing the format to PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb. Got this:
[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yma.png)

Comment: What is this? `for (int y = 0; y  255 ? 0 : x);`

Comment: @EricJ. it says *unsafe* :p

Comment: Looking at the result I could imagine that using a lineargradientbrush could achieve the same and __maybe__ quicker. But that could (both!) be wrong..

Comment: `Convert.ToByte` to convert int to byte... You can find even slower way but why?

Comment: @EricJ. - I viewed the source and for whatever reason, Stack is eliding a couple of lines in there. I think it's the less-than character.

Comment: If you want to go unsafe: use an int pointer, in this way you can write a pixel in one operation, much faster. Also, as Alexei said, dont use never Convert, is painfully slow. Reuse your bitmap, you don't need to create a new one each time, its very slow. And finally, the code you posted will not compile, the for is malformed.

Comment: My first thought is, measure time performance with a `Stopwatch` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx My second thought is, format your post so I don't have to scroll right to read your code.

Comment: The pixel format of the Bitmap is super-duper important.  There is no video adapter that runs at 24bpp, they all use 32bppPArgb today.  It is ten times faster than all the other ones, so you'll get 70 fps.  PArgb isn't that pleasant to deal with when you massage bits with LockBits() but it is a given that you don't use alpha so not a problem.  You'll get an additional speed up from being able to use `int*` instead of having to write 3 bytes, ought to get you near 100 fps.

Comment: @AdamV: The OP used a `<pre>` tag around the code, which caused the issue. I edited it.

Comment: Changed the < to (LESS THAN), html must have thought it was a tag starter.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I see you reseeding your random number generator every time.  Microsoft HIGHLY recommends not doing that.  You should instantiate your generator once, without passing a seed, and reuse the instance.

Comment: What are other other methods than Convert.ToByte

Comment: @BradleyUffner, fixed the random.

Comment: @Gusman, fixed the bitmap problem (recreating every time), and I am researching other methods for Convert.

Comment: ... use a simple cast.... (byte)(x > 255 ? 0 : x)

Comment: Thank you, changed it in my code.

Comment: Don't use `<pre>` tags to format your code. Just indent it at least 4 spaces or use the format as code button in the editor. That tag is what caused your less than symbols to be ignored.

Comment: What is that rnd used for? I can't find any other uses than the reseeding.

Also, I love how this question has no answers but loads of helpful comments! Must be a record of some kind? :) 

Is that code going to be available somewhere, sometime soon? :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the code you're benchmarking:

- rnd is useless (wrong copy/paste?)
- you're doing way too much multiplication, consider using:

Code:

```
for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
{
    int yTimeStride = y * stride;
    byte y2 = Convert.ToByte(y > 255 ? 0 : y);

    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    {
        int addressToAssign = (x * 3) + yTimeStride;
        byte x2 = Convert.ToByte(x > 255 ? 0 : x);
        ptr[addressToAssign] = x2;
        ptr[addressToAssign + 1] = y2;
        ptr[addressToAssign + 2] = 255;
    }
}
```

This will reduce multiplication with `y` from `Height*Width*3` to `Height` and reduce multiplication with `x` by 3.